# A non well formed numeric value encountered while trying to change date to number of day of week

Tags: php

```
foreach($bookings->results() as $bookings){

    $timestamp = $bookings->date; // outputs 2017-01-30
    echo $integer = idate('w', $timestamp);
}
```

Tried to change the date to an integer : `monday = 1` `tuesday = 2` etc

Answer (score 2):

`2017-01-30` is not a timestamp it is a string. So you have to convert that string to a timestamp.

Try this :

```
echo $integer = idate('w', strtotime($timestamp));
```